# Trying to put together a few assertion functions and i cannot get a try with to work

Tags: exception, testing, f#, assert

I am just learning F#, so i am trying a few things out(i do know could just use XUnit or something else)

I have the following assertion method, and the idea is that it should take an expected exception and the function that it expects to throw this exception, then execute the function and inside of the with test if the exception thrown is the same as the expected one.

```
let assertException (testName : string) (expected : 'a when 'a :> Exception) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested
        (false)
    with
    | :? Exception as someException when someException :? expected ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName expected) true 
            (true)
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName expected) false
        (false)
```

It gives me the error `Unexpected symbol '(' in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token.`  in the line where i try to call a print method. Shouldn't i be able to treat this `try ... with` as a

```
match ... with
```

??

And another question, could I do this a lot easier or?

Comment: *"could I do this a lot easier or?"* Yes, you could use [Unquote](http://www.swensensoftware.com/unquote), which is awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First,**
You're trying to use the type query operator `:?` with value `expected` of type `'a`. This operator cannot be used with values, only with types:

```
let x = box 5
let a = x :? int    // true
let b = x :? string // false

let y = 10
let c = x :? y  // error: type 'y' is not defined
```

In your example (working with exceptions), this would look like this:

```
someException :? InvalidOperationException
```

Or, if you want to compare with type parameter:

```
someException :? 'a
```

**Second**,
why do you even give name to `someException` if all you want to do is just compare its type? That's exactly what the `with | :?` clause is doing to begin with:

```
try
    ...
with
| :? 'a ->
   ...
```

And then, you don't actually need the value `expected`, since all you want to probe is the type. So you can just declare the generic parameter and do away with the regular one:

```
let assertException<'a> (testName : string) functionToBeTested =
   ...
```

**And finally,**
your `functionToBeTested` is not actually a function, since you're not calling it. If you want to verify that it throws a specific exception during execution, you need to actually make the call:

```
        functionToBeTested()
```

Putting it all together:

```
let assertException<'a when :> exn> (testName : string) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested()
        (false)
    with
    | :? 'a ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName typeof<'a>.Name) true 
            (true)
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName typeof<'a>.Name) false
        (false)
```

Comment: `expected` is needed in those `printTestResultInMiddle` calls ; also `'a` is missing a constraint `<'a when 'a :> exn>`

Comment: Thanks, added the constraint. `expected` is only needed in order to print out the type name.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently you need to put parentheses around the `when` expression here. And you need to be checking against the *type* of `expected`, which is `'a`. The following should compile (it worked for me when I replaced your `printTestResultInMiddle` calls with `printfn` calls):

```
let assertException (testName : string) (expected : 'a when 'a :> Exception) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested
        (false)
    with
    | :? Exception as someException when (someException :? 'a) ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName expected) true 
            (true)
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName expected) false
        (false)
```

However, that give a warning on the `:? Exception as someException` expression:

> warning FS0067: This type test or downcast will always hold

That's because according to the [`try ... with` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-try-with-expression), a bare identifier is equivalent to `:? System.Exception as <identifier>`. So you can simplify your function down to:

```
let assertException (testName : string) (expected : 'a when 'a :> Exception) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested
        (false)
    with
    | someException when (someException :? 'a) ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName expected) true 
            (true)
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName expected) false
        (false)
```

But actually, it's even simpler to do it this way:

```
let assertException (testName : string) (expected : 'a when 'a :> Exception) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested
        (false)
    with
    | :? 'a ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName expected) true 
            (true)
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName expected) false
        (false)
```

That also compiles when I try it in F# Interactive, though I haven't actually tested it. I do notice that your `functionToBeTested` in the `try` expression should probably be a function call (i.e., `functionToBeTested ()`. And you don't need those parentheses around the `(true)` and `(false)` expressions either.

So one more iteration of your code, as simple as I can make it without changing its semantics (and note that I *have* changed its semantics just a little bit with `functionToBeTested ()`) would be:

```
let assertException (testName : string) (expected : 'a when 'a :> Exception) functionToBeTested =
    try
        functionToBeTested ()
        false
    with
    | :? 'a ->
            printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s PASSED: Raised expected exception %A" testName expected) true 
            true
    | _ ->
        printTestResultInMiddle (sprintf "Test: %s FAILED: expected exception %A" testName expected) false
        false
```